# Prove trigonometric identity cos(2x) with rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How do one prove the following trigonometric identity with the standard rotation matrix $T_{θ}$

$cos(2θ) = cos^{2}(θ) − sin^{2}(θ)$?

---

The hint given is to compare $T_{2θ}$ and $T_{θ}◦T_{θ}$. We have not learned about complex numbers yet.

I have come to that:

$T_{θ}◦T_{θ}$= $\begin{bmatrix}cos^{2}\theta -sin^{2}\theta  & -2cos{}\theta sin \theta \\2sin \theta cos{}\theta  & cos^{2}\theta -sin^{2}\theta \end{bmatrix}$

$T_{2θ}$= $\begin{bmatrix}cos{2}\theta &  -sin{2}\theta \\sin{2}\theta & cos{2}\theta \end{bmatrix}$

Is it enough to show this and say that one element in the matrix equals the other element in the other matrix?

Comment: You have incorrectly computed $T_\theta \circ T_\theta$

Comment: Why do you think you might need complex number for this?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in computing $T_\theta\circ T_\theta$. Specifically, the top left and bottom-right entries are NOT 0.

Comment: Oh, we have not learned much about that notation either. Would you please show me how you compute it?

Comment: @Sam: It's just matrix multiplication. You're multiplying $T_\theta$ by itself. Are you familiar with matrix multiplication?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I corrected it now. Is it enough to say one element of Tθ◦Tθ is equal to T2θ?

Comment: @Sam: Yes, as with a 2x2 matrix, all four components must satisfy their respective equation